# How to Add project to Source Control (TFS) With TFS Web Access?

Tags: tfs

How to Add VS project to Source Control (TFS) without Visual Studio? I was also given a web access to tfs project but I did not see any upload option or create sub-project option (I see my main project "Project 333" and all the solutions under it, still talking about via web ui).

Answer (score 6):

You cannot upload a project to TFS via the web UI.  The web UI of TFS is for viewing source only, and keeping track of bugs/tasks and the general status of your code and builds.  You will need either Visual Studio or the TFS client installed in order to commit code to source control.